# Check if directed acyclic graph is feasible

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs

For a given directed acyclic graph *G* I'm looking for a way to verify if a list *L*, containing the activities, is precedence feasible. A resource-saving solution would be nice since the size of *G* may increase drastically.

Example:

[image]

```
G = {0: [], 1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [1], 5: [1], 6: [4], 7: [4], 8: [3,6,7], 9: [2,5,6], 10: [2,5], 11: [8,9,10]}
```

Now this list

```
L1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 9, 8, 11]
```

for example is feasible but

```
L2 = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 11]
```

is not because activity 0 is a predecessor of 1 and activity 5 is a predecessor of 10.

Comment: What exactly does "precedence feasible" mean? Are you looking for an ordering of the nodes? In this case, it might be confusing to talk about a "set", as those are typically unordered.

Comment: Sets in Python are unordered.  `S1` and `S2` are the same set in the Python language

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes I am looking for an ordering of the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question you want to check whether a given ordering of nodes is consistent with partial ordering defined by the edges in the graph. Maybe I'm missing something, but for this it should be enough to check for all edges `a ---> b` that the index of `a` in the list is lower than the index of `b`. If you create a dictionary mapping elements to their positions first, the complexity for this will be only `O(e)`, `e` being the number of edges.

```
def check(g, l):
    pos = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(l)} # for O(1) index
    return all(pos[a] < pos[b] for b in g for a in g[b])

G = {0: [], 1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [1], 5: [1], 6: [4],
     7: [4], 8: [3,6,7], 9: [2,5,6], 10: [2,5], 11: [8,9,10]}
L1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 7, 9, 8, 11]
L2 = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 11]
print(check(G, L1)) # True
print(check(G, L2)) # False
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I am stuck with the following problem: I changed my code so that the dictionary *G* inherits the successors instead of the predecessors: `G = {0: [1,2,3], 1: [4,5], 2: [9,10], 3: [8], 4: [6,7], 5: [9,10], 6: [8,9], 7: [8], 8: [11], 9: [11], 10: [11], 11: []}`. Can you please tell me how I can find all direct and indirect predecessors and successors for a given node (including the node itself) in a precedence feasible ordering? For node 8 for example I am trying to find a list `L = [0,3,1,4,6,7,8,11]` but not `L = [0,3,1,6,4,7,8,11]`.

Comment: @qualitaetsmuell I suggest you keep both your original G and your new G for this, and then do a depth-first-search starting at that node in both directions (once using the old G, then using the new G) to get the nodes "upsteam" and "downstream" of the node. For more detail, I suggest you post a new question.